# Azure Cloud Service with WCF: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version 4.0.0.0'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure

I have a .NET 4.5 Cloud Service with a WCF endpoint running in Azure and I have a .NET 4.0 WCF client that calls the service from a desktop application.  This has worked well for almost a year now, but recently one of my customers (only 1 out of all) has been experiencing a failure when the client calls the service.  Here is the stack trace as written in *the client's* logs:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at <my client code>...
```

I assume that this exception is being thrown on the server, but ultimately caught and logged by the client, because it includes the `Server stack trace` bit.  But how can that be when the other 99% of my customers are experience no problems whatsoever?

So here's the question: Given this setup, how can only one client reliably and uniquely cause this server-side exception?  What might be the problem?  Could client configuration cause some change in payload that would cause a different server-side code path?